# ideal() in R package pscl produces error

Tags: r, pscl

I would like to use the ideal() function in the `pscl` package in `R`. When I run the example provided in the help file, i.e.,

```
data(s109)
n <- dim(s109$legis.data)[1]
x0 <- rep(0,n)
x0[s109$legis.data$party=="D"] <- -1
x0[s109$legis.data$party=="R"] <- 1

id1 <- ideal(s109,
         d=1,
         startvals=list(x=x0),
         normalize=TRUE,
         store.item=TRUE,
         maxiter=260E3,
         burnin=10E3,
         thin=100)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Error in .C("IDEAL", PACKAGE = .package.Name, as.integer(n), as.integer(m),  : 
  wrong type for argument 18 in call to IDEAL
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I'm on OS X 10.13, using R 3.4.2 and pscl 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved with the new version of the `pscl` package (version 1.5.2), which has been released on 2017-10-10.